# Regular expression to find the text lines that do not contain a specific string using grep(linux terminal-opensuse)

Tags: regex, linux, terminal, grep

for example if i have 2 lines like

```
1.George Pappas george2 12136 Peristeri –-----
2. Nick Pappas nick4 11223 Aigaleo 5324123
```

i want to find the lines containing `Pap` but not `Aig`

the result must be line `1` since the `2nd` one contains `Aig`

i m completely new to terminal commands so let me know if something of what i said wasn't clear and needs more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
grep Pap input.txt | grep -v Aig
```

---

- `-v` means `invert-match`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
awk '/Pap/ && !/Aig/' file
1.George Pappas george2 12136 Peristeri .-----
```